# How to get First Non Repeating Character from a String in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

How to get first non repeating character from a String in PHP?

I have this sample string,

```
$string = "ABBGAACCE";

$string_array = str_split($string);

$temp_array = [];
foreach($string_array as $key => $value)
{
    if(array_key_exist($value, $temp_array))
    {
       // already exist!
    }else{
       $temp_array[$value] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What should the output be in this example?

Comment: @waterloomatt It should be `G`

Answer (score 1):

This one is a little shorter than my previous answer, using process of elimination while looping

```
 <?php
    $string = "ABBGAACCE";
    $newString = $string;
    $stringLength = strlen($string);
    $temp = [];
    
    for($i = 1; $i <= $stringLength; $i++)
    {
        $cur = substr($string,$i,1);
        if(array_key_exists($cur, $temp))
        {
            $newString = str_replace($cur,"",$newString);       
        }
        else
        {
            $temp[$cur] = 1;
        }
    }
    print_r(substr($newString,0,1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array_count_values to get single occurrence and then filter out get first value.

```
$string = "ABBGAACCE";
$stringArray = str_split($string);
$countArr = array_count_values($stringArray);
$singleton = array_filter($countArr, function($elem){return $elem==1;});
print_r(array_keys($singleton)[0]);
```